# UICollectionCell position issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout

[image]CollectionView cell is not coming at correct position. I am using following code to create the Collection view

```
 let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    viewListCollection = UICollectionView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero
    layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero

    viewListCollection.dataSource = self
    viewListCollection.delegate = self
    viewListCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    viewListCollection.tag = 9999
    viewListCollection.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SelectedContactCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SelectedContactCell")
    viewListCollection.scrollEnabled = true
    viewListCollection.collectionViewLayout = layout
    self.addSubview(viewListCollection)
```

blue colour is of CollectionView and yellow colour is of CollectionViewCell . You can see the top distance of the cell, why this space is coming.And how to remove that?

Comment: Which space are you talking about ?

Comment: can you see the image ?

Comment: No, I don't see the image.

Comment: please see now.

Comment: @Aashish Nagar is your NIb cell x and y values set to 0,0??

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```